# The unload event does not fire reliably for Jquery problem in a webpage

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I created a web page based with pure html, Bootstrap and query, It contains jquery-3.6.1.min.js ,
When I test speed the page in Gtmetrix it has this error:
`

> The unload event does not fire reliably and listening for it can
> prevent browser optimizations like the Back-Forward Cache. Use
> pagehide or visibilitychange events instead.

I checked and I found there is many unload functions in the Jquery file,

In this situation what should I do to fix this problem?

In this article I found I should use these bunch of codes

https://www.seochecker.it/learn-about/unload-listener/

const terminationEvent = 'onpagehide' in self ? 'pagehide' : 'unload';

```
addEventListener(terminationEvent, (event) => {
  // Note: if the browser is able to cache the page, `event.persisted`
  // is `true`, and the state is frozen rather than terminated.
}, {capture: true});
```

My question is that does it really work? if so where should I add this? to my javascript file or that query file?

Thank you.